# Splitting values using Jsoup library

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsoup

I need to split values from document.please help me how to do it using Jsoup library.

```
<div class="text">
  Flamingnet Student Book Reviewer  KThom
<br/>
     It's been eight years since the Assembly (an alien race) took over Earth and captured all the adult population. Eight years that Holt Hawkins has spent as a bounty hunter in a world ruled by rebel youths.  Holt is transporting his latest prisoner, Mira, to the Midnight City to collect his reward when the two come across a crashed Assembly ship with a young girl named Zoey trapped inside.  Together, they rescue Zoey and soon discover her magical abilities that could stop the Assembly for good.  The three embark on a treacherous journey across the barren wasteland they once called home, fighting for their own lives as well as each others'.
<p>Midnight City is an amazing book.  In the beginning, you don't really know how Earth was captured, but you know enough to be able to read and enjoy the book and learn more as the book goes on.  The author reveals the right amount of information throughout the book, otherwise there would be a whole history section that wasn't needed.  The book is fast-paced and never boring.  Once I started reading the book, I couldn't put it down.  The characters were original and intriguing because each had their own mysteries and backgrounds that you had to read to find out about.  I would recommend this book to anyone who likes action/sci-fi books with a little romance thrown in. </p>
<p/>
<p>Reviewer Age:17</p>
<p>
Reviewer City, State and Country: Brownsburg, Indiana United States of America
<br/>
</p>
</div>
```

**Expected output:**

```
name=Kthom
text =  It's been eight years since the Assembly (an alien race) took over Earth and captured all the adult population. Eight years that Holt Hawkins has spent as a bounty hunter in a world ruled by rebel youths.  Holt is transporting his latest prisoner, Mira, to the Midnight City to collect his reward when the two come across a crashed Assembly ship with a young girl named Zoey trapped inside.  Together, they rescue Zoey and soon discover her magical abilities that could stop the Assembly for good.  The three embark on a treacherous journey across the barren wasteland they once called home, fighting for their own lives as well as each others'.Midnight City is an amazing book.  In the beginning, you don't really know how Earth was captured, but you know enough to be able to read and enjoy the book and learn more as the book goes on.  The author reveals the right amount of information throughout the book, otherwise there would be a whole history section that wasn't needed.  The book is fast-paced and never boring.  Once I started reading the book, I couldn't put it down.  The characters were original and intriguing because each had their own mysteries and backgrounds that you had to read to find out about.  I would recommend this book to anyone who likes action/sci-fi books with a little romance thrown in.
Age=17
country = Brownsburg, Indiana United States of America
```

Comment: Have you tried reading any JSoup tutorials? For examle, getting the text shouldn't be more than something like: `Jsoup.parse(htmlString).getElementsByTag("p").first().text()`

Answer (score 0):

The source html is a bit *"wild"*, so there's no clean solution. To get those values, you have to mix ***Selectors*** and ***Regex***.

Here's an example *(please note, there's no error checking etc. yet!)*:

```
final String html = "<div class=\"text\">\n"
        + "  Flamingnet Student Book Reviewer  KThom\n"
        + "<br/>\n"
        + "     It's been eight years since the Assembly (an alien race) took over Earth and captured all the adult population. Eight years that Holt Hawkins has spent as a bounty hunter in a world ruled by rebel youths.  Holt is transporting his latest prisoner, Mira, to the Midnight City to collect his reward when the two come across a crashed Assembly ship with a young girl named Zoey trapped inside.  Together, they rescue Zoey and soon discover her magical abilities that could stop the Assembly for good.  The three embark on a treacherous journey across the barren wasteland they once called home, fighting for their own lives as well as each others'.\n"
        + "<p>Midnight City is an amazing book.  In the beginning, you don't really know how Earth was captured, but you know enough to be able to read and enjoy the book and learn more as the book goes on.  The author reveals the right amount of information throughout the book, otherwise there would be a whole history section that wasn't needed.  The book is fast-paced and never boring.  Once I started reading the book, I couldn't put it down.  The characters were original and intriguing because each had their own mysteries and backgrounds that you had to read to find out about.  I would recommend this book to anyone who likes action/sci-fi books with a little romance thrown in. </p>\n"
        + "<p/>\n"
        + "<p>Reviewer Age:17</p>\n"
        + "<p>\n"
        + "Reviewer City, State and Country: Brownsburg, Indiana United States of America\n"
        + "<br/>\n"
        + "</p>";


// -- Basic input parsing --
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element divTag = doc.select("div.text").first(); // Take first element found, if there are more, just iterate over them


// -- Name --
String name = divTag.childNode(0).toString();
name = name.split("Flamingnet Student Book Reviewer")[1].trim(); // Cut off, the things not needed

// -- Text --
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(divTag.childNode(2).toString().trim()); // Text is constructed from two tags
text.append(divTag.select("p").first().text().trim()); // 2nd Part (thats the one in p-tag)

// -- Age --
String age = divTag.select("p:matches((?i)Reviewer Age)").first().text().split(":")[1].trim();

// -- Country --
String country = divTag.select("p:matches((?i)Reviewer City*)").first().text().split(":")[1].trim();


// -- Output --
System.out.println("name=" + name);
System.out.println("text=" + text);
System.out.println("age=" + age);
System.out.println("country=" + country);
```

The method `split(":")[1]` is used to cut off the values description. It's always a good idea to `trim()` the strings, so leading / trailing blanks are removed.

Finally the output:

```
name=KThom
text=It's been eight years since the Assembly (an alien race) took over Earth and captured all the adult population. Eight years that Holt Hawkins has spent as a bounty hunter in a world ruled by rebel youths. Holt is transporting his latest prisoner, Mira, to the Midnight City to collect his reward when the two come across a crashed Assembly ship with a young girl named Zoey trapped inside. Together, they rescue Zoey and soon discover her magical abilities that could stop the Assembly for good. The three embark on a treacherous journey across the barren wasteland they once called home, fighting for their own lives as well as each others'.Midnight City is an amazing book. In the beginning, you don't really know how Earth was captured, but you know enough to be able to read and enjoy the book and learn more as the book goes on. The author reveals the right amount of information throughout the book, otherwise there would be a whole history section that wasn't needed. The book is fast-paced and never boring. Once I started reading the book, I couldn't put it down. The characters were original and intriguing because each had their own mysteries and backgrounds that you had to read to find out about. I would recommend this book to anyone who likes action/sci-fi books with a little romance thrown in.
age=17
country=Brownsburg, Indiana United States of America
```

For further documentation according to Jsoup-Selectors, please see [*Use selector-syntax to find elements*](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).